# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/DirectoryName/SubDirectoryName' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I am calling from an ASP.NET page to get a list of files and some related fields.  It fails when the dataset is filled and I am getting an error saying the conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.  The field is is referring to is a varchar with relative directory paths.  I don't really have a clue why this is happening.  An explanation and a solution for this problem would be greatly appreciated.  My stored procedure is below.

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[spFileDownload]
(
@Folder varchar(1000) = null,
@Keyword varchar(1000) = null,
@BatchID IntegerListTable readonly,
@OrgID IntegerListTable readonly
)

as

if @Keyword is not null
begin
    Select  fldFileName,
            fldRelativePathName,
            fldDescription,
            fldDateAdded,
            fldKeywords,
            fldBatchDescription
    from    tblReport
    inner join tblBatchLog
    on tblBatchLog.fldBatchID = tblReport.fldBatchID
    where   fldRelativePathName =ISNULL(@Folder, fldRelativePathName) 
            and Freetext(fldKeywords, @Keyword)
            and tblreport.fldBatchID in (Select n from @BatchID)
            and fldMembershipID in (select n from @OrgID)
end
else
begin
    select  fldFileName,
            fldRelativePathName,
            fldDescription,
            fldDateAdded,
            fldKeywords,
            fldBatchDescription
    from    tblReport
    inner join tblBatchLog
    on tblBatchLog.fldBatchID = tblReport.fldBatchID
    where   fldRelativePathName =ISNULL(@Folder, fldRelativePathName) 
            and fldRelativePathName in (select n from @BatchID)
            and fldMembershipID in (select n from @OrgID)
end
```

Edit:  I failed at reading.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and fldRelativePathName in (select n from @BatchID)` aren't you comparing a string `fldRelativePathName` to ints ?

Comment: Thanks.  I feel dumb now for not catching that.  No wonder it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line...

```
and fldRelativePathName in (select n from @BatchID)
```

Column "n" is an integer so SQL is trying to coerce fldRelativePathName